# Line Feed from PDF417 barcode scan causes Chrome to open the download tab

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I need to allow a user to scan their drivers license and get the information from it replacing CR and LF characters with \n and \r. The problem comes when Chrome sees the LF it opens the downloads tab. I am trying to use jQuery to see and process these control characters, so far to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?? I have tried  e.preventDefault(); on the keydown event of the textbox that the information is being scanned into, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes when the PDF417 is scanned into a textbox... you have to prevent the textbox from allowing the CTRL codes to work... with Javascript and jQuery, here is what I did to make this work... I know people have been trying to find the code that makes this happen... so, here it is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $("textarea").focus();
 var DLElements = [];;
    $("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
        // if <LF><CR> is detected, break the line
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 17) {
        DLElements.push( $("#textarea").val() );
        $("#textarea").val( "" );
        e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        // Listen for <CTRL> J
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 74) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        // Listen for <CTRL> M Mute
        if(e.ctrlKey && e.which == 77) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        }

    });

        $("#parseMe").click(function(e) {
            //alert("Clicked");
            $.each(DLElements, function(key, value) {
                $("#textarea2").append("||" + value + "\n");
            });
        });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<label for="textarea">Raw data</label>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
<textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2"></textarea>
<button id="parseMe">Parse Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Just save this code and open it in a browser - this one was designed for Firefox but may work in others... and scan your ID... and watch the magic happen...

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to solve this. I tried many methods and found them to be inconsistent.

First, on your textarea input, you want to listen to the `@focus` and `@blur` events to turn on (and off) the event listeners for keyboard input.

When the textarea is in focus, you want to add the following event listener.

```js
var myData = '';
var previousKey = '';

eventListener (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    if (event.key.length === 1) {
        if (previousKey == 'Control' && event.key == 'j') {
            myData += '\n'
        } else {
            myData += event.key
        }
        previousKey = event.key
    }
}
var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea')

textarea.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', eventListener);
});

textarea.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
  document.removeEventListener('keydown', eventListener);
});
```

Essentially you stop all keyboard input when the input is in focus and record all character input into a variable substituting a newline character every time Chrome sees Ctrl + J.

Then you just need to parse `myData` as a drivers license.

When the user clicks out of the input box, the event listener goes away so the keyboard will work again.